# Javascript function not being called onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function close() {
  console.log('close');
  $("#display").hide();
}
```

I am trying to call a closefunction when the user clicks out of the input box, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Doesn't work:

```
<input type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery"  onblur="javascript: close();" onkeyup="javascript: getSuggest(); "/>
```

Works:

```
<input type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery"  onblur="javascript: alert('msg');" onkeyup="javascript: getSuggest(); "/>
```

getSuggest returns false if that's relevant.

Comment: onblur="javascript: close();" <-- you don't need "javascript:" in any event handers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function name from close to something else since the close function is part of the window object.

Additionally your function declaration cannot be specified after any type of dom-ready event observers have fired.

Example: notice if you wait for window.load or dom.ready the function doesn't get attached to the dom element (input)

EDIT
http://jsfiddle.net/bb84T/5/

Answer (score 2):

`close` is a native function [**[docs]**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close). You can't use that name. So

`close();` is really `window.close()`

try:

```
<script>
function closse() {
  alert('close');
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery" onfocus="closse();" "/>
```

Comment: Definitely rename `close()`, but to `closse()` with two s's? Why not give it a more descriptive name like `hideDisplay()` (since that's what it does)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript: within your onblur.  Change to this:

```
<input type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery"  onblur="close();" onkeyup="getSuggest(); "/>
```

*edit* Try changing to jQuery events instead of DOM events:

```
<input type="text" name="searchQuery" id="searchQuery">

<script>
$(function () {

  $("#searchQuery").on("blur", function () {
    console.log('close');
    $("#display").hide();
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: No, I don't get any errors however 'close' doesn't get outputted either.

Answer (score 1):

You should use unobtrusive javascript instead, and inside your `$(document).ready()` add use the [.blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) function built in jQuery instead, like this:

```
$('#searchQuery').blur(function(){
    myClose();
});
```

You also need to rename your close function, because it is reserved according to [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close) (thanks to @Mike Stewart)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need onblur event in HTML? Maybe better attach jQuery 'blur' event to the element?
Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VaVy8/

Answer (score 0):

onblur is disabled on google chrome (this will work on firefox and IE)
You can use

```
$('#searchQuery').bind('blur', close);
```